# I am having error to display the image file save in memory in android,

Tags: java, android

Here is the code:

```
public void Displayimg(View v) {

    File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraApp");


    ipath[0] = String.valueOf(((TextView) v).getText());


    String  sifile = ipath[0].substring(45,52);  // extracting the filename from the view eg: abc.jpg


    File imgfile = new File(path,sifile);  // it fails on this line with unfortunately, main application has stopped. 

    // if the sifile conatians a name of the file that exist, it give error and comes out
    // if I give file name in sifile that does not exisit, if give file does on exisit and comes our with error.
    // Basically I am having problem to open an image file that exisit and dispaly.


    // File("/storage/sdcard0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/Zimg20151105_1535133.Jpg");



    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mc_imgview);

    if(imgfile.exists()){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),file.getAbsolutePath() + "File Exisit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),file.getAbsolutePath() + " File Does not Exisit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

Comment: what is the error? please post your logcat output

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of that .substring(45,52)?

Comment: Nanoc, it appears to grab the file name from the url

Answer (score 1):

Display image :

Try to Search `Volley` or `Universal-Image-Loader` or `Glide`.

Save Image:

```
    public static String getSdPath(){
        //todo test path
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
//        return "";
    }

    public static String getImageDir (String type,Activity activity){
        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("pure")){
            return getSdPath()+ activity.getDir("pure", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
        }else{
            return getSdPath()+activity.getDir("deal", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
        }
    }

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "test";
    private static final Uri IMAGE_URI = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    private static final String PATH = getImageDir("deal", mActivity);

    public static Uri savePngImage(ContentResolver cr, Bitmap bitmap) {
        long dateTaken = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String name = String.valueOf(dateTaken) + ".png";
        return savePngImage(cr, name, dateTaken, PATH, name, bitmap);
    }

    public static Uri savePngImage(ContentResolver cr, String name, long dateTaken, String directory,
                                   String filename, Bitmap source) {

        OutputStream outputStream = null;
        String filePath = directory + File.separator + filename;
        try {
            File dir = new File(directory);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            File file = new File(directory, filename);
            if (file.createNewFile()) {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                if (source != null) {
                    source.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
                } else {
                }
            }
//            FileUtils.updateFile(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            return null;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return null;
        } catch (NullPointerException ex) {
            return null;
        }finally {
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                }
            }
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(7);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, name);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, filename);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, dateTaken);
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, filePath);
//        FileUtils.updateFile(filePath);
        return cr.insert(IMAGE_URI, values);
    }
```

Comment: Universal-Image-Loader is great!